# Pycharm: How do I set up my run configurations so that I can see all tests in a certain path?

Tags: pycharm, pytest

I am using pytest in PyCharm for my unit-tests.

#### Wanted View

I want to have a view with an overview of all tests under a certain path.
This view should show the latest result that I got for running them (ideally before even running them once).

I can see them fine once I run all tests.

#### Issue

Every time I pick a single test and rerun it,
then 'Test Results' will only show the single test that I ran most recently. I lose all information about other tests.

How can I set up my run configuration so that I get all unit tests in path `root/test`?

Edit: Here's an illustration of my issue
For the sake of simplicity, I'll illustrate my issue for a single module (but ideally I want to keep information over all my unit tests in my test directory).
First, I run the tests for my module test_synchronizer.py:

[image]

I see now that there are two failing tests. I'd execute one of them to take a closer look and then I end up with this:

[image]

In practice this makes it difficult to move from test to test, fixing them one by one without rerunning the tests all the time (or keeping track of the failing ones manually).

Comment: There are no stupid questions! I rearranged in the form of Context-Wanted-Problem-Question. Maybe some screenshots can support your question.

Comment: Thanks. I've also added screenshots that hopefully explain my situation better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your described practice:

> to move from test to test, fixing them one by one without rerunning the tests all the time (or keeping track of the failing ones manually).

is very well supported by the tools (pytest CLI and PyCharm IDE).
It often is documented by following title.

### Rerun failed tests

When running test, we usually strive to make all pass and get them green.
If few of them fail, we want to rerun those only (not all passed again).

#### PyCharm button

PyCharm supports this strategy and task, manually or automatically.

See the docs:

- [Rerun failed tests](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/rerunning-tests.html#rerun-failed-test)﻿

  > In the *Test Runner* tab , click the **Rerun Failed Tests** button [image: Rerun Failed Tests icon] on the toolbar.
- [Rerunning tests automatically](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/rerunning-tests.html#auto)﻿

### pytest CLI

See the *session-based* testing and *cache* concept of pytest in docs.
It is supported by the CLI, see the docs for [Rerunning only failures or failures first](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/cache.html#rerunning-only-failures-or-failures-first):

> `--lf`, `--last-failed` - to only re-run the failures.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to be able to have a higher level of control like only running one of my failed tests while keeping information about what else passed/failed, in particular if test execution isn't that fast (e.g. I'm running a series of integration tests). This is still close to what I wanted so I'll be using that going forward. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get a listing of all tests found by `pytest` without running them, use `pytest --co -q`:

Here's an example where I ran it on my own test suite:

```bash
pytest --co -q
boilerplates/boilerplate_test.py::MyTestClass::test_boilerplate
boilerplates/classic_obj_test.py::ObjTests::test_data_url_page
boilerplates/sb_fixture_test.py::ObjTests::test_data_url_page
boilerplates/samples/google_test.py::GoogleTests::test_google_dot_com
boilerplates/samples/sb_swag_test.py::MyTests::test_swag_labs_login
boilerplates/samples/swag_labs_test.py::MyTests::test_swag_labs_login
boilerplates/samples/test_page_objects.py::MyTests::test_page_objects
```